# Is there a way to change text background color of the items in Windows Explorer in Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-7, delphi-xe2, windows-explorer

[image: http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/39000/39972/xentient-labels-1.jpg]

Is is possible to change background color of the items in Windows Explorer like the [`Xentient Labels`](http://xentient-labels.en.softonic.com/) application does ? Is it possible to do so from Delphi XE2 in Windows 7 ?

Comment: If I were King, all file listings would always be in black and white, monospaced text.  But that's just me, I guess ;)

Comment: As Hans Passant said [`here`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/netfxbcl/thread/0c206a47-64ec-47b5-a1f9-c7a1d5ad1194) it won't work in Windows 7. You would find the handle to the Windows Explorer's list view and use as the easiest way the [`ListView_SetTextBkColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro.

Comment: It would be great if you could add some blinking text in there too

Comment: @David, yeah blinking text and jumping items :-) I'll try it...

Comment: I checked and this Xentient Labels doesn't work on Windows 7 and isn't registered as shell extension.

Comment: ListView in Windows 7 has the `DirectUIHWND` class name and doesn't listen to the list view messages, so it's *not possible* in Windows 7.

Comment: Or icons that have a hiccup like those on a Mac ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's *not possible* to do this in Windows 7 since the Windows Explorer's list view uses the `DirectUIHWND` not `SysListView32` as it was in Windows XP. The `DirectUIHWND` class control doesn't listen the list view messages, so you cannot use the [`ListView_SetTextBkColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro to change text back color as you could on Windows XP.

With the following simple test you can verify it. Let's have an edit box and button on the form. In that edit box enter the handle to the Windows Explorer's list view control (obtained e.g. by Spy++) and in button's press run the following code:

```
uses
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListViewHandle: HWND;
begin
  ListViewHandle := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  ListView_SetTextBkColor(ListViewHandle, $0000CCFF);
end;
```

This Spy++ screenshot from Windows 7 shows the class name of the Explorer's list view (in Windows XP it was `SysListView32` controllable by standard list view messages, the `DirectUIHWND` doesn't react to them).

[image]

Comment: Now looking at the picture from question, the [`ListView_SetTextBkColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro wouldn't be the right one. It changes the color background for all items in a list view. However it still doesn't change the fact the list view in Windows 7 Explorer doesn't listen the list view messages, so there's no need to search for the right one in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't color text, but you can add overlays like TortoiseSVN/CVS/Git/Groove/Dropbox/etc. does.

[image: Screenshot of Explorer with overlay icons]

(from https://tortoisesvn.net/screenshots.html)

Comment: link: Access forbidden, reload plz to other any image host

Comment: If the link is forbidden, just click enter on the address bar for the site with the forbidden error and it will now load. Forbidden links usually check the location you were sent from, by pressing enter on the address bar again you trick the site into thinking you are accessing the link directly from the site :)